# How to create a color of the same brightness and saturation?

Tags: color-theory, color-spaces

Let's consider three colors: Red, Green and Blue. For blue I created a specific shade, something like #F2F5F7. If you see this color, it has a certain level of shade, brightness and saturation value of blue.

I want to create the same equivalent color but for Green and Red, how to get that?

Comment: Did you mean to say "but from Green and **Red**"?

Comment: Hi Faraz, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: use adobe kuler for a fast way.

Comment: I'd like to say that with your example, the difference between the three colours is going to be nigh invisible--all three of them are almost white.

Comment: Consider using the [Lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space): "Unlike the RGB and CMYK color models, Lab color is designed to approximate human vision." There's a color calculator at [easyrgb.com](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=CALC) and conversion formulas [RGB->XYZ](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=02#text2) and [XYZ->Lab](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=07#text7). One way to use this for your case would be to pick any green color, convert to Lab, adjust `L` to equal the `L` of the blue, and then convert back to RGB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what the HSB colour model is for. You have almost exactly named the model's variables in your question:

- **Hue** is the 'kind' of colour: red, blue, orange, yellow;
- **Saturation** is inverse with the amount of white you add to the hue;
- **Brightness** is inverse with the amount of black you add.

So, to take your example colour of #F2F5F7. you can convert this into HSB in Photoshop or Illustrator's colour picker, yielding H=203, S=1, B=96 as HSB values.

All you have to do now is change the H to the hue you want. For a green, try H=83 and leave the S and B values intact. This is converted by the colour picker right away and yields #f3f4f2.