# How can I create a color palette with the same saturation levels as a particular color?

Tags: color, color-theory, palette, saturation

Say I have #FF3154 (as red). How could I come up with palette in which all the colors (different hue, as in orange, yellow, blue, etc...) are in harmony with that specific red, that is, all share the same saturation level.

Is there any software of automating such process?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nearly all graphics applications can just rotate hue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up stumbling upon [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-create-a-color-of-the-same-brightness-and-saturation?rq=1) question, which helped me out a lot.

[This link](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-converter-01.htm) did the trick as well. Pretty much just played around with the hue and it did the trick.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the links in your answer itself so that people don't have to go somewhere else to find the answer to your question!